# Add icu4c (and other libs) to bazel project

Tags: c++, bazel

I have a project that builds via CMake and requires a lot of manual installations of additional deps. I want to migrate this project to Bazel and make these libs automatically downloadable. I found a solution for Boost, but I can't understand how to add icu4c and other libs which builds via other tools.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to make use of third-party libraries using Bazel. The chosen approach depends on different properties of the third-party library, e.g.: Does the third-party library already support Bazel? Is the library available only as a pre-build package? Does the library use code generators, or any other tools, or transitive dependencies?

Given the example of [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) which uses CMake as build system you can proceed as the following:

#### First approach: Inject a BUILD file

In your `WORKSPACE` file you can do something like:

```py
maybe(
    new_git_repository,
    name = "fmt",
    branch = "master",
    remote = "https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt",
    build_file = "//third_party:fmt.BUILD",
)
```

The corresponding `fmt.BUILD` file can look like this:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "fmt",
    srcs = [
        #"src/fmt.cc", # No C++ module support
        "src/format.cc",
        "src/os.cc",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "include/fmt/args.h",
        "include/fmt/chrono.h",
        "include/fmt/color.h",
        "include/fmt/compile.h",
        "include/fmt/core.h",
        "include/fmt/format.h",
        "include/fmt/format-inl.h",
        "include/fmt/locale.h",
        "include/fmt/os.h",
        "include/fmt/ostream.h",
        "include/fmt/printf.h",
        "include/fmt/ranges.h",
        "include/fmt/xchar.h",
    ],
    includes = [
        "include",
        "src",
    ],
    strip_include_prefix = "include",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Advantages:

- fmt-8.01 does not have out-of-the-box support for {fmt}. This way Bazel can make use of {fmt} without the need that {fmt} knows anything about Bazel
- fmt-8.0.1 needs not to be modified

Disadvantages:

- Reinvent the wheel: Every Bazel project that wants to use {fmt} has to reinvent this `fmt.BUILD` file.
- Maintenance costs: If different Bazel projects want to adapt to future versions of {fmt} every single project has to do this maintenance by its own. Maybe new files will be introduced.
- Missing Knowledge: Maybe for some reason, it makes sense to define some special defines upfront, etc. It also takes some time and knowledge of {fmt} to set up such a `BUILD` file. What is the best practice to build this lib?

#### Second approach: Bazelize {fmt}

Add a `WORKSPACE` file and `BUILD` file to the {fmt} repository.

This way {fmt} gets bazelized and can be used in your Bazel builds.

You could use it then this way:

**Example**

Create a `WORKSPACE.bazel` file with the following content:

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

# Fetch bazelized fmt
git_repository(
    name = "fmt",
    branch = "bazel-support", # A copy of master where BUILD.bazel, WORKSPACE.bazel, .bazelrc and .bazelversion are moved to root
    remote = "https://github.com/<user_or_organisation>/fmt", # replace <user_or_organisation> by a valid account
)
```

Create a `BUILD.bazel` file and add a dependency to {fmt} (wit the content of `fmt.BUILD`).

In favor of keeping the {fmt} project directory clean, those files were not added to the project root directory (see [here](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/pull/2505) for details).

#### Third approach: Using the {fmt} repository with Bazel

Even though the {fmt} repository does not contain a `WORKSPACE` file in its root directory, there is an easy approach to use the {fmt} repository with Bazel out of the box. This is demonstrated in the following example.

Add to your `WORKSPACE` file:

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "new_git_repository")

# Fetch all files from fmt including the BUILD file `support/bazel/BUILD.bazel`
new_git_repository(
    name = "fmt_workaround",
    branch = "master",
    remote = "https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/",
    build_file_content = "# Empty build file on purpose"
)

# Now the BUILD file `support/bazel/BUILD.bazel` can be used:
new_git_repository(
    name = "fmt",
    branch = "master",
    remote = "https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/",
    build_file = "@fmt_workaround//:support/bazel/BUILD.bazel"
)
```

Create a `BUILD.bazel` file and add a dependency to {fmt}:

```py
cc_binary( # Build a binary
    name = "Demo", # Name of the binary
    srcs = ["main.cpp"], # List of files - we only have main.cpp
    deps = ["@fmt//:fmt"], # Depend on fmt
)
```

Make use of {fmt} in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "fmt/core.h"C

int main() {
  fmt::print("The answer is {}.\n", 42);
}
```

The expected output of this example is `The answer is 42`.

#### Forth approach: Make use of patch_cmd

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

git_repository(
    name = "fmt",
    branch = "master",
    patch_cmds = [
        "mv support/bazel/.bazelrc .bazelrc",
        "mv support/bazel/.bazelversion .bazelversion",
        "mv support/bazel/BUILD.bazel BUILD.bazel",
        "mv support/bazel/WORKSPACE.bazel WORKSPACE.bazel",
    ],
    # Windows related patch commands are only needed in the case MSYS2 is not installed
    patch_cmds_win = [
        "Move-Item -Path support/bazel/.bazelrc -Destination .bazelrc",
        "Move-Item -Path support/bazel/.bazelversion -Destination .bazelversion",
        "Move-Item -Path support/bazel/BUILD.bazel -Destination BUILD.bazel",
        "Move-Item -Path support/bazel/WORKSPACE.bazel -Destination WORKSPACE.bazel",
    ],
    remote = "https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt",
)
```

More details [here](https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BazelDemos/tree/master/fmt).

## Other libraries

I have written a few blog posts about Bazelizing different libs:

- [Bazel: Bazelizing Qt5 for macOS](https://vertexwahn.de/2022/02/13/bazelizeqtmacos/)
- [Bazel: Bazelizing Embree 3.13.0](https://vertexwahn.de/2021/07/30/bazelizingembre3.13.0/)
- [Bazel: Bazelizing Qt5 & Qt6](https://vertexwahn.de/2021/06/06/bazelizeqt/)
- [Bazel: Handling external dependencies in OpenEXR](https://vertexwahn.de/2021/04/02/externaldependenciesbazelopenexr/)
- [Bazel: Offical support for OpenEXR](https://vertexwahn.de/2021/03/14/officialbazelsupportopenexr/)
- [Bazel: Bazelizing OpenEXR](https://vertexwahn.de/2021/01/24/bazelizeopenexr/)
- [Bazel: Bazelizing Embree 3.12.1](https://vertexwahn.de/2021/01/12/bazelizingembree3.12.1/)